# Seeking advice to reopen a question

Tags: discussion

Recently my question, "[Did Christ assume our fallen humanity?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/38743/did-christ-assume-our-fallen-humanity)" was closed. I need an input on how to reopen that question. Should I change it into, "Did the early Church Fathers believe Christ assumed our fallen humanity?" I wonder why my question was closed for being an opinion based? Would then any question asking about did Christ has two natures by definition an opinion based because Non-Chalcedonians reject it? I'm still confused by what constitute as non opinion based question. Because in one way or another all religious question is by definition an opinion based like, "[Did the biblical apostle James visit Ireland?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/20809/did-the-biblical-apostle-james-visit-ireland)". Please help me to clear things out. Thank you.

Comment: "Should I change it into, 'Did the early Church Fathers believe Christ assumed our fallen humanity?'" That would be answerable and therefore openable. Is it what you want to know?

Comment: Thank you for visiting meta to get help on your questions, and also for keeping a polite tone and attitude during what is probably a frustrating moment. To help keep that frustration from overwhelming you, I've written a post: [Newcomers: Be patient. You will get there if you follow our direction. Keep trying](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1927)

Comment: On a note about your example, that is on a different site with different guidelines and a different topic. With history, there is no belief and faith involved. There is either evidence for a statement/conclusion or there is not.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude yes, it answers my question. Thanks.

Comment: I would have thought a different, and perhaps more helpful question would be: What evidence or reasoning is there that supports Christ assumed our fallen humanity.?

Answer (score -1):

No subject matter can be truly objective, nor is any subject matter truly subjective.  Individual questions may be wholly objective or wholly subjective, but here most fall somewhere in between (though usually closer to the objective side).

Your question was never really very opinion based, but it *was* a Truth question.  The actual matter of Christology is a matter of faith and, [for better or for worse](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193/brothers-we-are-not-christians), this site has [forsworn answering questions of faith](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255/pastoral-advice-questions?lq=1) ([addendum](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1588/but-cant-i-just-say-one-thing/1601#1601)).  If you ask, instead, what X group believes about Christology, we can certainly help you because your question is no longer a Truth question but instead about doctrine.

The sneaky way you can get Truth questions answered here is to ask "What do I believe about X?", where 'I' is replaced with your denomination of choice.  Of course, this works better for people like me (Roman Catholic) who are part of a denomination that believes questions about X to be objectively answerable or demonstrably unanswerable in a manner consistent with a good SE [frame challenge](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3318/how-do-we-handle-a-desire-to-challenge-the-frame-of-a-question).  Note that this is advice from internet 'experts' and you should probably use it as a springboard into your own investigations rather than accepting it at face value.

**You DO NOT need to ask this question in a manner restricted to the Church Fathers**  You do need to ask it in a manner restricted to a group, though.  Btw, that group can be '[Christians](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/884/what-is-mainstream-christianity/888#888)', if you want.

(The second to last link above goes to the meta.rpg thread on frame challenges.  Replace it with the Christianity thread if there is one.  I saw [this](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4302/are-change-of-frame-answers-allowed-on-this-site) but its a very oblique approach to the issue that's really more focused on a different one.  It's also not very highly upvoted.)

Comment: "Christians" would be too broad.