# What is the recommended editing that would help get the essence of a specific question reopened?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I came across an old question [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/13805/why-did-mary-ask-jesus-to-make-wine-at-the-wedding-at-cana?rq=1).

It was closed without a lot of dialog on why it was closed. Was it because it was more of a "truth question"? What would it take to reopen the question - e.g. change it to something like "what do xxx write about xxx"? Was it closed because of denominational infighting?

This closed question, without any attempt by moderators to edit it and/or make suggestions to edit it, is a typical type of thing that I've often encountered on SE. It makes me resonate with [this comment](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6001/im-new-here-and-im-having-some-difficulty-understanding-guidelines-for-questio):

> ...it just seems to me that this site tends to stifle good discussion
> on Christianity more than encourage it. I looked down the list of new
> questions and just saw close after close.
>
> So I guess my question is, what is the purpose of this site? What I
> loved about Stack Overflow (and why I joined that site) was that it
> seemed so friendly to new and inexperienced users. I expected a
> similar atmosphere here, but I feel like inexperienced users are
> beaten down with clarification notices and scoldings and down votes
> and close votes.

Answer (score 3):

That's a [Locked](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/locked-posts) question, as opposed to a [Closed](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) question.

It was locked when we decided to add the limitation that we really needed a denominational perspective for most exegetical questions.  I wasn't a mod then, but I agreed whole heartedly because it was not fun to post a really good Catholic answer to a generic post and get no traction on my answers because I quoted the Catechism or the saints.

So I believe the old mods locked a number of higher voted posts, as examples of good questions that are just no longer on topic, as opposed to closing or deleting them.

There's no way to salvage this question without deleting a majority of the answers, I'd encourage you to ask it again (not right now though, since you've got a handful of related questions waiting for good answers) under the normal guidelines.

- Ask about a doctrine connected to the passage

or

- Ask about denomination's perspective on the passage

Comment: I guess that's how the game is played. It seems like a major part of asking a question on SE is to be able to parse the phrasing of a question, with just the right nuanced words, so as to not have it be closed or locked.

Comment: @jess we're extremely unlikely to lock any posts at this point.  But yeah, it's tricky and people are prickly sometimes.  If you think something's unfair you can always flag a post.

Comment: @Jess I don't think it's difficult to ask a question here, as long as the type of question is on-topic. If you haven't seen it, make sure you read [What types of questions can I ask on this site?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3409/6071)

Answer (score 1):

I've unlocked it and closed it instead. This is an exegesis question that belongs at the Biblical Hermeneutics site, but it's too old to migrate.

Comment: Reading the rules is one aspect of how the language game in creating questions can be played. But offering suggestions by moderators, in how to apply the rules, is a more uplifting way of dealing with questions that are not phrased in a precise manner.

Comment: @Jess I do post suggestions to questions so many times. But not on a nine year old question. But if the OP is interested in editing their question they can now that it's no longer locked.

Comment: that’s ok. I just brought it up as an example of how good questions can be canceled because of some linguistic shortcoming.